# git how to remove remote refs on server

Tags: git

Per accident we pushed with `--mirror` and this results in having some additional refs on the server repo.

We can see all the additional refs simply by ( Example only):
`git ls-remote repo_mirror refs/remotes/*`

```
22f860d115435693545aef85d81a7a11c29586ac    refs/remotes/play/master
f2a62d053b911696f9166bdc07ea6da648706120    refs/remotes/play/br1
f2a62d053b911696f9166bdc07ea6da648706120    refs/remotes/repo_all/br1
22f860d115435693545aef85d81a7a11c29586ac    refs/remotes/repo_all/master
```

I can now manually delete each of these single refs with:
`git push repo_mirror --delete remotes/play/br1`

Is there an option to delete all `/remotes/*` with a single command or loop?

Comment: Maybe you might be able to put all the remote branches into a file (one branch per line) and then use `cat branches.txt | xargs git push -d` ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, any kind of scripting is possible by handcrafted things. But I saw so many git options and for_each... that I am in hope to learn how I can proceed with more "gitty" like operations :-)

Comment: `git push -d` refuses glob patterns such as `refs/origin/*`, so @evolutionxbox ' s suggestion to ` ... | xargs git push -d` is your best course.

Answer (score 0):

As getting from the comments, there is no native git command to do the stuff, I ended up in:

`git ls-remote repo_mirror refs/remotes/* | sed -e 's/[0-9a-z]*[ \t]*//'| xargs -n1 git push repo_mirror --delete`